# button onPress not working after implementing animation

Tags: flutter, dart

I just implemented animation to my floating action button group so that it will expand/collapse onTap. It worked but now I can't use any of those expanded buttons.

onPressed function of those button inside animtedPositioned not working.
(can't even see ripple effect).

```
floatingActionButton: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          AnimatedPositioned(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            bottom: isExpanded ? 140 : 0,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: resetCounter,//not working
              child: const Icon(Icons.restart_alt),
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 130),
            bottom: isExpanded ? 70 : 0,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: _incrementCounter,//not working
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                turns += 1.0 / 2.0;
                isExpanded = !isExpanded;
              });
            },// its working
            child: AnimatedRotation(
              turns: turns,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              child: Icon(Icons.expand_less),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like need a height for your stack wrap it with container and give it height, also align your buttons bottom and it should be fine.

```
floatingActionButton: Container(
  height: 200,
  child: Stack(
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
    children: []
  ),
),
```